# Proof Regarding an N-dimensional hypercube

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

We know that the distance between two nodes in a graph is the length of the shortest path between those two nodes.

If given an n-dimensional hypercube and a fixed single starting node s, how many nodes are at a distance of exactly i from s, assuming $0$ $\le$ $i$ $\le$ $n$?

How would I go about proving that as well?

Comment: Do you know of the representation of the hypercube in terms of binary strings? Have you tried that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are exactly $\binom{n}{i}$ (binomial coefficient) vertices at distance $i$ from any particular vertex $V$.

Proof: Let us encode the vertices of the hypercube by $n$-tuples of $0$s and/or $1$s. Selecting a vertex at distance $i$ from the fixed vertex $V$  amounts to change exactly $i$ of the $N$-tuple associated with $V$; the numbers of ways to do that corresponds with the definition of $\binom{n}{i}$.

Remark:

1) one checks that there is a single vertex that is at maximal distance $i=n$ from $V$ (because $\binom{n}{n}=1$) : it is obtained by "complementing" the encoding of $V$.

2) in the case of the ordinary cube, we can visualize the sequence 1,3,3,1 for the number of vertices at distance 0,1,2,3 resp. from a certain vertex (see figure below where the reference vertex is taken in $A$; points at distance 1 are $B,D,E$, points at distance 2 are $C,F,H$, point at distance 3 is $G$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Would it be best then, since I need to write a more formal proof, to use proof by induction?

Comment: I don't think so. It would complexify things. The proof, as given, can be considered as rigorous. The only thing you could modify is to**define** the hypercube as being $\{0,1\}^n$, and speak of "Hamming distance" (the number of binary digits that have changed between two binary sequences, i.e., two vertices $V_1$ and $V_2$.). Besides, I have added to my answer the simple example of a 3D cube where one can visualize the cases 1,3,3,1. (line $n^{o}3$ of Pascal's triangle.)